# Spring - 404 when using declarative list

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a list in Spring via declaration in application-context.xml

```
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.check" />

<bean id="valueOptions">
    <property name="valueList">
    <list>
        <value>Value A</value>
        <value>Value B</value>
    </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

When I try to run this code , I am getting

`SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
atorg.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:186)`

and I am getting a 404 when trying to run the application. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Update

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:857)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:829)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The reason I am saying it is related to the list creation is because if I remove the list and the corresponding usage in my xhtml file, the application works fine.

Comment: can you please share the full error message? It might not be related to the list declaration at all.

Comment: @melihcelik updated with the entire stack trace

Comment: Is the XML that you shared the real XML that you are using? If not, can you share the original one after anonymizing the names/values?

Comment: yes this is the same XML I am using - have just replaced the values

Comment: The reason why I thought there was something missing in the XML was that, I did not see the "class" attribute on the bean definition but @Jean already replied. So it's OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the class attribute for the bean element in your xml file...

```
<bean id="valueOptions" class="your.package.ObjectName">
    <property name="valueList">
    <list>
        <value>Value A</value>
        <value>Value B</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If your bean is an implementation of the List object, you can do something like this :

```
<bean id="valueOptions" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>Value A</value>
            <value>Value B</value>                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Or use the util namespace :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">


<util:list id="valueOptions" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>Value A</value>
    <value>Value B</value>   
</util:list>
```

Comment: Well you have made my question sound naive:) You are a saviour.Thanks a lot for the answer.  What I wanted to achieve was the third approach. BTW if I have to access the list "valueOptions" from my JSP page, how will I bind it?

Comment: No I dont think so. I am not seeing any spring mvc jars in my "lib" directory. So I believe it is right to say that it is not using "Spring-MVC". Sorry -I am checking some legacy code and considerably new to Spring

Comment: There is many way to access the list in your jsp, it depends on the technologies you are using.